# JMF and Incoming tcp audio

Tags: java, audio, tcp, rtp, jmf

I'm on a project of VoIP.
I've a audio stream over TCP from my mobile to my computer. I need get this stream and send it by RTP (with SIP) to a device.

I can talk to the device in SIP with JAIN-SIP, but I can't send the audio, I don't know how to do this.
I'm using JMF, I already define a custom DataSource but I can't create the Processor with it...

Any ideas ?

Thanks for helping :)

Code :

Inside RTPLayer constructor :

```
dataSrc = new DataSource(is, contentType);
dataSrc.connect();
Format[] format = { new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR, sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channel) };
ProcessorModel pm = new ProcessorModel(dataSrc, format, new ContentDescriptor(contentType));
p = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(pm);
```

Custom DataSource :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.media.Duration;
import javax.media.Time;
import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.InputSourceStream;
import javax.media.protocol.PullDataSource;
import javax.media.protocol.PullSourceStream;

public class DataSource extends PullDataSource {
    private InputSourceStream[] m_sources;
    private ContentDescriptor m_cd;
    private boolean m_connected;
    private InputStream m_is;

    public DataSource(InputStream is, String contentType) {
            super();
            m_connected = false;
            m_cd = new ContentDescriptor(contentType);
            m_is = is;
    }

    @Override
    public PullSourceStream[] getStreams() {
            if (!m_connected) {
                    throw new java.lang.Error("Source is unconnected.");
            }
            return m_sources;
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
            m_sources = new InputSourceStream[1];
            m_sources[0] = new InputSourceStream(m_is, m_cd);
            m_connected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect() {
            if (m_connected)
                    m_connected = false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
            if (!m_connected)
                    throw new Error("Source is unconnected.");
            return m_cd.getContentType();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getControl(String arg0) {
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getControls() {
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Time getDuration() {
            return Duration.DURATION_UNKNOWN;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws IOException {
    }

}
```

InputStream :

```
socket = server.accept();
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
rtpLayer = new RTPLayer(getHost(), remoteAdress, is, SEND_RCV_RTP_PORT, remotePort, ContentDescriptor.RAW_RTP, sampleRate, bufferSize, 1);
```